# Simple ASP.NET MVC SQL related question

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-2

Good Morning,

I have the following code:

```
  public ActionResult ViewCategory(int category)
    {
        var items = from indexVariable in DatabaseEntities.classifieds
                    where indexVariable.category = category
                    select indexVariable;
        return View(items.ToList());
    }
```

This code doesn't work, the error is on the where line. I am sure you can all see what I am trying to achieve, I want to only pull up results for the specified category.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double `==` for boolean expressions, the simple `=` is an assignment operator:

```
where indexVariable.category == category
```

Comment: Cheers, that was a completely stupid question on reflection. But I was sat there trying to figure it out for an age.